# Unable to login to TFS service from IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: tfs, intellij-idea, azure-devops

I just switched to IntelliJ 13 yesterday. And I tried to connect to microsoft tfs service (online service) using IntelliJ 13. This is my address http(s)://(myname).visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection username:(myoutlookname).outlook.com password (myoutlookpassword), then it gives me "Transport 401 Error, not authorized". I also tried in eclipse and tfs works fine. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?
  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Quote from microsoft "ALTERNATE AUTHENTICATION CREDENTIALS
Some applications that work outside the browser (including Team Explorer Everywhere command line client and the git-tf utility) require basic authentication credentials. Other applications do not properly handle using an e-mail address for the user name during authentication.

To work with these applications, you need to enable alternate credentials, set a password, and optionally set a secondary user name not in the form of an e-mail address. Please note that alternate credentials cannot be used to sign in to the service from a web browser or outside of these applications"
To do this, you have to go to your profile page->credentials->Enable alternateive credentials->Set a password, or (alter username), then you can use your TFS in IntelliJ.

Comment: Hey, that's a good step forward, though I am still facing the issue of "http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92752" Have you ever faced this? Did you get over it / are you using maybe older version?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays a Personal Access Token is the way to go.

```
https://(myname).visualstudio.com/_details/security/tokens
```